# how to know the phone or system connected to my modem in android?

Tags: android, connection, device, modem

I want to know how many phone or system connected to my modem?
I tried to scan the IP from 1 to 254 for discovering connected devices. but when im trying InetAddress.isreachable(2000) it works on my phone but does not work on some devices (always return True or always return false).
I also tried to ping the devices but it also worked on my device but did not work on some devices.
I also tried to make a socket to devices but when target's device is Linux like Android it did not work.
Is there anyway to know the devices connected to my modem in android?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Network Scanner that you can think of : [android-network-discovery](https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery)

Features : Discover Machines on a LAN (connect/ping discovery, dns discovery) , TCP Port Scanner (connect() scan)

Comment: thank you friend :) but that doesn't work on all devices too. isn't there someway else for discovering devices?

Comment: yw, unfortunately i don't know another way,Good luck